# DataFrame().round() AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'reindex'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding, attributeerror

I am getting the AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'reindex' when I try to round a DataFrame. 
Please see below an example:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([(.21, .32), (.01, .67), (.66, .03), (.21, .18)],
              columns=['dogs', 'cats'])
df.round(1)
```

The result is:

```
File "<ipython-input-41-7ebbeaa04631>", line 1, in <module>
df.round(1)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7458, in round
    concat(new_cols, axis=1), index=self.index, columns=self.columns

  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 408, in __init__
    data, axes=dict(index=index, columns=columns), dtype=dtype, copy=copy

  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 189, in _init_mgr
    mgr = mgr.reindex(

AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'reindex'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems broken pandas, try upgrade/reinstall

Comment: Your code works fine at my end, seems to be some issue with Pandas.